# Upgrading Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade

Can someone please tell me how to upgrade Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04 ... it gives an error that "third party sources are disabled".. I don't know how to enable them.

Comment: @Jobin not a dupe.

Comment: That message is only informational, there should be another message instead. [Edit] your question and include it.

Comment: no this is what is happening when i click the upgrade button it starts and then at the point of "Software List" it stops and gives an error that "Third party sources are disabled" and suddenly it closes the setup